# New/Import controller in Design Studio SAP

Tags: sapui5, pentaho-design-studio

I want to import / create a new control for "Design Studio to the SAP".

The control will be a calendar of the month only.
For example: Sap.m.DateTimeInput. 
Which will show only the months and years (not days). ()

[image: Example image]

I failed to import the control from SAPUI5.
I searched the internet and not found a way for import control to the SAP Design Studio

I would appreciate help,guides or any words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom component which implements the calendar control using the Design Studio SDK (see the SDK guides here: @ https://help.sap.com/boad), then install it in the client.